# actionscript - syncronizing 2 sound channels?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using 2 sound channels to play 2 separate, externally loaded mp3 files at the same time.  Right now I have the play button tied to a function that starts the first mp3, then the 2nd.  The problem is - the 2nd mp3 starts a few milliseconds after the first.  Is there a way that I can make sure these 2 start playing at the exact same time?

```
function playMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{

    channel = myMusic.play(songPosition);
    channel2 = myMusic2.play(songPosition);
    myTimer.start();
    btnPlay.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

Edit:  I found a clumsy workaround that matches the TIMER for the 2 audio sources.  It works, but now I have a hiccup at the beginning while i tries to match:

```
    function updateTime(evt:TimerEvent):void
    {
        lblSongTime.text = convertTime(channel.position);
        if(channel.position!=channel2.position){   
 trace("out of sync")                
 SoundMixer.stopAll()
    channel = myMusic.play();
    channel2 = myMusic2.play(channel.position);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `channel.position` instead of `songPosition` when you initially call `myMusic2.play`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that out last night while looking for a fix.  Still starts out of sync.  I'm thinking it must be an actionscript bug.  Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the glitch at the beginning I believe.  In the playMusic function, I set the volume of both channels to 0.  Then after sync correction I turn the volume back up.  Clumsy, but works, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting flash player 10+, then you can use the [`sampleData` event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#event%3asampleData) and [`extract` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29) of the sound class to combine the two sounds.

Basically, you'll want to make a Sound subclass that handles the `sampleData` event by passing the position to the `extract` method of each of the two sounds you want to play. Then, you'll combine the two [`ByteArray`s](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) and insert that into the event's `data` member.

The main thing to be careful about is that you can only give a maximum of 8k of data (if I remember correctly) to the `sampleData` event at a time. You'll also probably want to average the two sounds, or at least reduce the volume when combining the sounds.

It's been a little while since I've written actionscript, so it'd take me a little time to write up some code for you, but if you still need help, let me know and I'll try to give you more info or some code.

**EDIT**

Here's a minimal class that'll do what you want. You should add error checking and you may need to add stuff to handle sound transforms (e.g. volume adjustment) as using the sample data event may ignore a sound transform you apply at play (I don't remember, but it shouldn't be too hard for you to figure that out ^_^)...

```
import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class DualSound extends Sound {
    private var sa:Sound;
    private var sb:Sound;

    public function DualSound(a:Sound, b:Sound) {
        super();

        sa = a;
        sb = b;

        addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, handleSampleData);
    }

    private function handleSampleData(e:SampleDataEvent):void {
        var ba:ByteArray, bb:ByteArray;

        ba = new ByteArray();
        bb = new ByteArray();

        sa.extract(ba, 8 << 10, e.position);
        sb.extract(bb, 8 << 10, e.position);
        ba.position = 0;
        bb.position = 0;

        while(ba.bytesAvailable > 0 && bb.bytesAvailable > 0) {
            e.data.writeFloat((ba.readFloat() + bb.readFloat()) / 2);
        }
        if(ba.bytesAvailable > 0) {
            e.data.writeBytes(ba, ba.position, ba.bytesAvailable);
        } else if(bb.bytesAvailable > 0) {
            e.data.writeBytes(bb, bb.position, bb.bytesAvailable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're saying.  I did find a pretty clumsy work around - basically it checks to see if the TIMER for audio2 matches the TIMER for audio1.  The problem is now that it skips for a second after hitting play while it tries to match:

 function updateTime(evt:TimerEvent):void
 {
  lblSongTime.text = convertTime(channel.position);
  
  if(channel.position!=channel2.position){   
 trace("out of sync")                
 SoundMixer.stopAll()
  channel = myMusic.play();
 channel2 = myMusic2.play(channel.position);
 
  }
 }

Comment: @user, I've added code for a class that'll do what you want if you're not satisfied with your workaround.